# Как правильно сделать компоновку?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml, layout

Как исправить отступ и сделать более простой код:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        id: _rootLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        spacing: 10

        ColumnLayout {
            id: _1_2_6
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: (_rootLayout.width - _rootLayout.spacing) * 0.66
            RowLayout {
                id: _1_2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Rectangle {
                    id: _1
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.preferredWidth: (_1_2_6.width - _1_2_6.spacing) * 0.33
                    color: "green"
                    Text {
                        text: "1"
                    }
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: _2
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.preferredWidth: _1_2_6.width - _1_2_6.spacing - _1.width
                    color: "lightgreen"
                    Text {
                        text: "2"
                    }
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: _6
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: (_1_2_6.height - _1_2_6.spacing) * 0.33
                color: "grey"
                Text {
                    text: "6"
                }
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            id: _3_4_5
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: (_rootLayout.width - _rootLayout.spacing) - _1_2_6.width
            Rectangle {
                id: _3
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "lightgray"
                Text {
                    text: "3"
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: _4
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "orange"
                Text {
                    text: "4"
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: _5
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "skyblue"
                Text {
                    text: "5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: пример1]
[image: пример2]

Как можно увидеть между левой и правой колонкой больше отступ чем в других местах. Так же промежуток между 4-5 не всегда совподает по высоте с промежутком 2-6 (скрин 2).

Еще мне не нравится, что если у `_1_2_6` будет больше колонок, нужно будет отнимать больше spacing'ов (например так: `Layout.preferredWidth: (_rootLayout.width - 2 * _rootLayout.spacing) * 0.66`). Нельзя ли задать коэффициент растяжения как в QWidget layout Stretch?

И последнее, в логи выводится сообщение "`Qt Quick Layouts: Polish loop detected. Aborting after two iterations`", когда я по горизонтали уменьшаю размер. Почему?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Grid https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-grid.html, или  GridLayout https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html

Comment: спасибо, но это решит только одну из проблем (разной высоты промежутка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @AlexanderChernin за совет использовать Grid*.

А еще я понял, что `Layout.preferredWidth` <s>можно</s> нужно использовать как коэффициент растяжения, подобно layout stretch.
Результат такой:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    GridLayout {
        id: _grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        columnSpacing:  10
        rowSpacing: 10
        columns: 3
        rows: 3
        Rectangle {
            id: _1
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            color: "green"
            Text {
                text: "1"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: _2
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.rowSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 3
            color: "lightgreen"
            Text {
                text: "2"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: _6
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "grey"
            Text {
                text: "6"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: _3
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            color: "lightgray"
            Text {
                text: "3"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: _4
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            color: "orange"
            Text {
                text: "4"
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: _5
            Layout.row: 2
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 2
            color: "skyblue"
            Text {
                text: "5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: результат]